For each match select player identifiers of the home player/team
I have a table with match identifiers and corresponding player/team identifiers expressed as home_id. Each team tid consist of two players and each player has its own identifier pid. In table matches I don't know whether the column home_id represents a team or a single player.
I would like to add the columns home_ids for each match which represent the player identifiers of the home player/team. I wrote the following query that gives:

Result: row value misused

SELECT match_id,
CASE WHEN (SELECT pid FROM players WHERE m.home_id = pid)
            IS NULL THEN (SELECT pid_1, pid_2 FROM teams WHERE m.home_id = tid)
        ELSE (m.home_id)
    END AS home_ids
FROM matches m

How to modify my query so it works as intended?
Table matches:



match_id
home_id




18707060
149612


18707060
548355


18389439
146458


18389439
316081


18389511
334757


18389511
402979


18390491
87940


18390491
185150


18390555
164088


18390555
164374


18390785
95493


18390785
532349


14487258
24552


14487258
306032



players:



pid




87940


185150


164088


164374


24552


306032



teams:



tid
pid_1
pid_2




149612
149613
149728


548355
316251
316343


146458
146728
235888


316081
316073
316081


334757
334750
316079


402979
558506
558508


95493
315993
315997


532349
563020
563022



Desired output:



match_id
home_ids




18707060
(149613, 149728)


18707060
(316251, 316343)


18389439
(146728, 235888)


18389439
(316073, 316081)


18389511
(334750, 316079)


18389511
(558506, 558508)


18390491
(87940)


18390491
(185150)


18390555
(164088)


18390555
(164374)


18390785
(315993, 315997)


18390785
(563020, 563022)


14487258
(24552)


14487258
(306032)




This seems to give you what you want - though you really ought to fix your data model first:
SELECT M1.MATCH_ID
,P.PID HOME_IDS
FROM MATCHES M1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PLAYERS P ON M1.HOME_ID = P.PID
WHERE P.PID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT M2.MATCH_ID
,T1.PID_1||', '||T1.PID_2 HOME_IDS
FROM MATCHES M2
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEAMS T1 ON M2.HOME_ID = T1.TID
WHERE T1.TID IS NOT NULL
order by 1,2
;


LEFT OUTER JOIN PLAYERS P ON M1.HOME_ID = P.PID WHERE P.PID IS NOT NULL  can be rewritten as JOIN PLAYERS P ON M1.HOME_ID = P.PID. A similar rewrite can be used for the other leg in the union.

You have all the data you need, you are just not selecting it. Something like this should help:
SELECT m.match_id, p.pid AS p_pid, t.pid_1 AS t_pid_1, t.pid_2 AS t_pid_2
FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN players p
ON m.home = p.pid
LEFT JOIN teams t
ON m.home = t.tid
WHERE
   NOT (
           p.pid IS NULL AND
           t.tid IS NULL
       )

Essentially, we select all matches whose player or team exists with the criteria of m.home matching the correspondent id. The problem that you will likely face is that a tid may be equal to a pid, so the two may be confounded.
